# c# loop in public static class

Tags: c#, loops, class, static

i'm new in c# and trying to make loop in class, but don't know how to do it ;v

need to do something like that:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    using [...]


    public static class MyClass
    {
        private const string Options = [...];


        [Option("option#")]
        public static void Option#([...])
        {
            [...]
        }



        # is value from for loop {i} and below is inside loop 
        e.g.

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {

            [Option("option{i from loop}")]
            public static void Option{i from loop}([...])
            {
                My code
            }

        }
```

How can I achieve this? I need add command / public in the loop to the class MyClass. Loop generate command and public for command, and add to the class when i run the compiled .exe file, not when i generate .exe
Every help is welcome, have to learn;)

Comment: You have the `public static` contained **inside** the loop. You need it to the other way around. The `public static` will be **containing** the loop.

Comment: Stop! and step away from the keyboard, Please start by reading the basics [Classes (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes) and [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) and [Iteration Statements (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/iteration-statements) and [for (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for)

Comment: Also [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) also [C# Class](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-class)

Comment: Okay, thanks :) Reading time start

Comment: What exactly is the class supposed to do? Can you provide a more concrete example of what you want? Generally loops, along with other code execution, happens inside methods, which are contained in classes.

Comment: Class contains "commands" for the app like:   `[Option("add")]
public static void OptionAdd(string option)
{
 [...]
}
`
and i need create one command x times only with changed number

Comment: What is a "command", and what does a "command with changed number" mean? Is it just a string with different suffixes, like `"Command1", "Command2", "Command3"`, and are they stored in some type of collection, like a `List<string>`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a `static` class that adds strings (along with a number) to a private list through a method called `AddCommands`, which uses a `for` loop. It uses a `foreach` loop to show the commands in the `ShowCommands` method:

```
static class Commander
{
    private static List<string> Commands;

    public static void AddCommands(string command, int count)
    {
        if (Commands == null) Commands = new List<string>();

        int startValue = Commands.Count + 1;
        int endValue = startValue + count;

        for (int i = startValue; i < endValue; i++)
        {
            Commands.Add(command + i);
        }
    }

    public static void ShowCommands()
    {
        if ((Commands?.Any()).GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            foreach (var command in Commands)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(command);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are no commands available.");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("-------------------\n");
    }
}
```

And here's an example of it in use:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before adding any commands the list looks like:");
        Commander.ShowCommands();

        Commander.AddCommands("SomeCommand", 5);
        Console.WriteLine("After adding 5 commands the list looks like:");
        Commander.ShowCommands();

        Commander.AddCommands("AnotherCommand", 5);
        Console.WriteLine("After adding 5 more commands the list looks like:");            
        Commander.ShowCommands();

        Console.WriteLine("Done! Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Wow, upvote for an the amount of effort for such a low quality and ambiguous question

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void MyAwesomeChangingMethod(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

...

// now you can call it many times with a different number
MyAwesomeChangingMethod(1);
MyAwesomeChangingMethod(3);
MyAwesomeChangingMethod(675675);

// or

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    MyAwesomeChangingMethod(i);
```

***Note*** : If this is not what you want, you really need to explain your question better (not in comments)

Comment: I need something like the t4 template, but when I start the built-in application.

Automatic generation of commands, e.g.
`for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {

            [Option("option{i from loop}")]
            public static void Option{i from loop}([...])
            {
                My code
            }

        }`

When i start .exe the loop add command / public contained in it are to be add to the class x times. it's not about printing text, just typing it in a class to make the program read it as a command

Comment: @Nitr0o you realise none of this information is in your question? its fairly important stuff, you really need to update your question with lots more information

Comment: Ya, I have to precisely specify the question, because only I know what i want ;v sorry